# How I can Update only relevant data with this Update Controller?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb

**Update Controller**

```
exports.UpdatePanelMembers = (req, res) => {
  const { panelId } = req.params;
  if (panelId) {
    Panel.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: panelId },
      {
        panelMembers: {
          member1: {
            memberId: req.body.panelMembers.member1.memberId,
            fullName: req.body.panelMembers.member1.fullName,
            username: req.body.panelMembers.member1.username,
          },
          member2: {
            memberId: req.body.panelMembers.member2.memberId,
            fullName: req.body.panelMembers.member2.fullName,
            username: req.body.panelMembers.member2.username,
          },
          member3: {
            memberId: req.body.panelMembers.member3.memberId,
            fullName: req.body.panelMembers.member3.fullName,
            username: req.body.panelMembers.member3.username,
          },
        },
      }
    ).exec((error, result) => {
      if (error) return res.status(400).json({ error });
      if (result) {
        res.status(202).json({ result });
      }
    });
  }
};
```

In this code, if I update member1 details only, other data will be erased. So I want to update only relevant data like this postman JSON.

**Postman JSON Code**

```
{
    "panelMembers": {
        "member1": {
            "username":"john.j",
            "fullName":"John Jade",
            "memberId":"member123"
        }
    }
}
```

**Postman**
[image]

**Frontend is like this**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You just have to update member1 in panelMembers object. So for that, send member1 object in request from postman and make your query as :-

```
Panel.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: panelId },{'panelMembers.$.member1': member1})
```

This will only update member1 object. Other objects will not be affected or erased.

Comment: Not only the member1. If I want to update member2 also, how do I do it at the same time?

Comment: That will also be updated the same way. Panel.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: panelId },{panelMembers.$.member1: member1, panelMembers.$.member2: member2})

Comment: This code getting some errors. how can I show the screenshot of the code?

Comment: You can edit the question and add screenshot of error.

Comment: Done. I think now you can see the problem

Comment: Panel.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: panelId },{'panelMembers.$.member1': member1, 'panelMembers.$.member2': member2}).  I have added quotation marks. Now please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245100/discussion-between-shewani-and-jaspreet-kaur).